# How do i write a file in node js with name containing some date and time string in it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write a file with fs  like:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
let d = new Date();
let filename = "Source-" + d.getDate() + "\/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "\/" + d.getFullYear() + "-";
filename += (d.getHours() + "\:" + d.getMinutes());
filename += ".txt";
console.log(filename);
let p = path.join('./',filename);
fs.writeFile(p,"Something",(err)=>{
    console.log(err?err:'Success!');
});
```

**This Logs**

> Source-4/1/2018-12:15.txt
>
> { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\ttttt\Source-4\1\2018-12:15.txt'
> errno: -4058,
> code: 'ENOENT',
> syscall: 'open',
> path: 'E:\ttttt\Source-4\1\2018-12:15.txt' }

File is not written and the above error comes.

How can I resolve this so that I am able to write file with a date and time in its fileName.

Comment: try writing `let p = path.join(__dirname+'/'+filename);`

Comment: That doesn't help I'm having the same error.

Comment: there is only 1 possible error here... which is you doesn't have the folder prepared for the file to create to

Comment: I have the folder in which I'm writing the file as you can see I'm writing in `./` which is the same folder in which my source file is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not insert `/` in your file name
try removing them use something else like `-` or `_`